# Как вернуть из запроса на добавление сгенерированный id в PostgresSQL?

Tags: java, postgresql

У меня есть такой запрос:

```
insert into tasks (task_id, author, header, description, create_time)
values (default, (?), (?), (?), now()::timestamp)
```

Который я отправляю через JDBC Driver вот так:

```
public void addItem(final Item item) throws SQLException {
    // Так я генерирую запрос приведенный выше.
    final String requestPattern = this.requests.generate("add_item");

    if (item == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException();


    try (final PreparedStatement statement =

                 this.connection.get()

                         .prepareStatement(requestPattern)) {



        // First position = author.
        statement.setString(1, item.getNameUser());

        // Second position = header.
        statement.setString(2, item.getHeader());

        // Treed position = description.
        statement.setString(3, item.getDescription());


        statement.executeUpdate();
    }
}
```

И как говориться, все бы было ничего еслиб знала от кого. Когда я выполняю этот запрос я не знаю какой `id` присвоит postgres моему кортежу. Я знаю что можно как-то получить это значение прямо в рамках запроса на добавление. Но как? и как мне через JDBC драйвер его принять из моего `statement`?

Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: Если вдруг никто не ответит, то можно посмотреть на [этот ответ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1915197/3432401).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

После выполнения запроса, надо запросить сгенерированные ключи:

```
statement.executeUpdate();

ResultSet rs = statement.getGeneratedKeys();

if (rs.next()) {
    id = rs.getLong(1); //вставленный ключ
}
```

**Update**

Как верно заметил @Regent запрос надо выполнять с флагом `Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS`

```
 statement.executeUpdate(sql, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
```

или

```
PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(sql, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
```

Comment: а почему getLong(1) а не getInt?

Comment: ой а уменя rs.next() сразу false возвращает(((

Comment: `getLong()` почему? А бес его знает какого у вас типа идентификатор

Comment: @Павел если у вас `rs.next()` сразу возвращает `false`, то, возможно, вы не указали `Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS` при создании запроса.